# In which Veda it is mentioned that one should immediatly leave when there is a blasphemy?

Tags: vedas, bhagavata-purana

In the following paragraph, it is mentioned that there is a Vedic statement asking to leave the place whenever blasphemy is happening. When I check the actual statements from Srimad Baghavatham, it is not explicitly saying that the statement has Vedic sanction. But the writers mentioned so.

> .....Śiśupāla went crazy because of Kṛṣṇa’s being elected the supreme,
> first-worshiped person in that meeting, and he spoke so irresponsibly
> that it appeared he had lost all his good fortune. Being overcast with
> misfortune, Śiśupāla continued to insult Kṛṣṇa, and Lord Kṛṣṇa
> patiently heard him without protest. Just as a lion does not care when
> a flock of jackals howl, Lord Kṛṣṇa remained silent and unprovoked.
> Kṛṣṇa did not reply to even a single accusation made by Śiśupāla, but
> all the members present in the meeting, except for a few who agreed
> with Śiśupāla, were very much agitated because it is the duty of any
> respectable person not to tolerate blasphemy against God or His
> devotee. Some of them, who thought that they could not properly take
> action against Śiśupāla, left the assembly in protest, covering their
> ears with their hands in order not to hear further accusations. Thus
> they left the meeting, condemning the action of Śiśupāla. **It is the
> Vedic injunction that whenever there is blasphemy of the Supreme
> Personality of Godhead, one must immediately leave. If he does not do
> so, he becomes bereft of his pious activities and is degraded to a
> lower condition of life.** ....
>
> [[CHAPTER 74: The Deliverance of Śiśupāla, 10, Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam]](https://vedabase.io/en/library/kb/74/)

So, I want to know the name of the Veda that mentions the fact. Which Veda says that one should leave the place wherever insult to god/goddess happen?

Comment: talking and hearing insults both are sins.

Comment: Related --- When Guru's insult is going on one has to put fingers on one's ears and immediately leave the place. This is mentioned both in Smritis and in Tantras.